# Insert into multiple tables based on what user choose ? PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm doing a project, and in the AddJob Page, I need to add a record into a table in myslq based on   meaning the user choose where the rocord will be save into.

this is my code, and till now, it's only save the record into Food Table.how can I make it optional..

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['username']) ){

     if(isset($_POST['add'])){

        if(isset($_POST['add'])) 
        {
          $errorMessage = "";

           if(($_POST['lists'])== 0)  // trying to get error if user don't choose.
              {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot to Choose !</li>";

              }

              if(empty($_POST['JobName'])) 
              {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Job Name !</li>";

              }
              if(empty($_POST['Description'])) 
              {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Description !</li>";
              }

            if(empty($_POST['NoStudent'])) 
              {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Student Number !</li>";
              }

            if(empty($_POST['dueDate'])) 
              {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Due Date !</li>";
              }

              $lists = $_POST['lists'];
              $JN = $_POST['JobName'];
              $DES = $_POST['Description'];
              $NoS = $_POST['NoStudent'];
              $DuDate = $_POST['dueDate'];
              if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
              {
                echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
                echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
                die();
              } 


            }

            //////// IF all test passed.. then connect to db
             $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root" ,"" ,"CIE") or die ("cannot connect : ".mysqli_error());

          $sql = "INSERT INTO Food (JobName,Description,NoStudent,DueDate) 
          VALUES 
          ('$JN','$DES','$NoS','$DuDate')";


           mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

          echo "You Successfuly Added a new Reocord ...";
          mysqli_close($con);

     }

     else {  echo '
    <form action= "AddJob.php"  method = "post">
    <table width ="100%" cellpadding ="4" border="1" >

    <tr>
    <th>Select a Catagory</th>
    <th>Jobs Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th> No Students needed</th>
    <th>Due Date</th>
    </tr>';
        echo "<tr>
     <td>". 

    "<select name = lists >
      <option name= nothing value= 0 selected >Choose a Catagory</option>
      <option name= nothing value= 1>    Advertising     </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 2>    Fiscal          </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 3>    Food            </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 4>    Shopping        </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 5>    Rentals         </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 6>   Setting up       </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 7>    Performances    </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 8>  Registration/Ushering  </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 9>   Master of Ceremonies  </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 10>    Cleaning up   </option>
      <option name= nothing value= 11>    Others        </option>

     </select>"
      ." </td>
     <td> "."<input type=text name=JobName maxlength=50  placeholder='Enter Job Name '>" ." </td>
     <td> "."<input type=text name=Description maxlength=50 placeholder='Enter Description '>" ." </td>
     <td> ". "<input type=text name=NoStudent maxlength=50   onkeypress=return isNumber(event) placeholder='ONLY NUMBERS'/>" . "</td>
     <td>". "<input type=text name=dueDate maxlength=50 placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD'>" ." </td>
     </tr>";
     echo '
     </table>
     <br/>
     <div align="center">
     <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
     <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
     </div>
     </form>
     ';
    }
}else{echo "must logout to see this page..!!";}
?>
<html>
<head><title> Add.. </title></head>
<br>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unclear what your asking, can you explain some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your 11 tables have the same structure (fields names), you can just replace "food" table name by a variable, initialized by a "switch" on "$lists" variable content.
a simple version could be something like this :

```
$table="";       
switch($lists)
{
    case 1:
        $table ="Advertising";
    break;
    case 2:
        $table ="fiscal";
    break;
.........other cases..........
    case 0;
    default;
        echo 'Unsupported category';
    break;
}
if ($table != ""){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ". $table . "(JobName,Description,NoStudent,DueDate) 
                          VALUES 
                          ('$JN','$DES','$NoS','$DuDate')";
}
```

Comment: a table for each job type is a bad idea

Comment: As I've said, it's a simple solution to quickly unlock him without making a lot of modifications in the code. However you are true, if he can spend time rethinking his database (relations) and his code (huge use of html code in php,...). But he can progress step by step

Answer (score 0):

This is going to get wordy but I promise there's code at the end.

Presuming you actually have 11 tables, @dev35000's solution of using a PHP variable when building the SQL query is for you.

However, as all the tables appear to hold the same kind of data, you can make things easier on yourself by creating a table with a CategoryId. You could call that table Jobs (or whatever makes sense to you. I say jobs as that is what it appears you are storing) You would then make a table to store all the different categories.

The tables you'd end up with are:

```
`Jobs` Table
-----------------------
JobId       | JobName       | Description | NoStudent   | DueDate     | CategoryId
INT, PK, AI | VARCHAR(50)   | VARCHAR(50) | VARCHAR(50) | VARCHAR(50) | INT
-----------------------
Filled with data inserted through the form

`Category` Table
-----------------------
CategoryId  | Category
INT, PK, AI | VARCHAR(50)
-----------------------
1           | Advertising
2           | Fiscal
3           | Food
4           | Shopping
5           | Rentals
6           | Setting up
7           | Performances
8           | Registration/Ushering
9           | Master of Ceremonies
10          | Cleaning up
11          | Others
```

JobId and CategoryId would be [auto_incrmenting columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)
You're already sending the CategoryId so you're code won't actually change there. To display what category from the `Category` table a `Job` table record belongs to, you can use a `JOIN` in SQL to display what category a job belongs to with a query like this:

```
SELECT j.JobName, j.Description, j.NoStudent, j.DueDate, c.Category
FROM Jobs j
JOIN Category c ON j.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
```

Before we get to the code:

1. You had 2 checks for `isset($_POST['add'])`. Removed the inner one
   as it was redundant
2. I used full variable names instead of just abbreviations. I think that will make your code easier to read (for yourself and
   others) changing it back to abbreviations won't break anything.
3. I switched your code to take advantage of prepared statements which will protect against SQL injection
4. Give some kind of indentation scheme a change (I realize taking code from your IDE to StackOverflow messes up the formatting. Apologies if that's what happened here)
5. I switched your form to consistently use single quotes

---

```
<html>
    <head><title> Add.. </title></head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['add'])) {

        $errorMessage = "";

        if(($_POST['lists'])== 0) { // trying to get error if user don't choose.
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot to Choose !</li>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['JobName'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Job Name !</li>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['Description'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Description !</li>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['NoStudent'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Student Number !</li>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['dueDate'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot To Enter A Due Date !</li>";
        }
        if(!empty($errorMessage)) {
            echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
            echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
            die();
        }

        $JobName = $_POST['JobName'];
        $Description = $_POST['Description'];
        $NoStudent = $_POST['NoStudent'];
        $DueDate = $_POST['dueDate'];
        $lists = $_POST['lists'];

        //////// IF all test passed.. then connect to db
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root" ,"" ,"CIE") or die ("cannot connect : ".mysqli_error());

        $sql = "INSERT INTO Jobs (JobName,Description,NoStudent,DueDate,Category) 
        VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        // reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)) {
            // reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssisi', $JobName, $Description, $NoStudent, $DueDate, $lists);


            mysqli_execute($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

            echo "You Successfuly Added a new Reocord ...";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else {
        echo "
<form action= 'AddJob.php'  method = 'post'>
    <table width ='100'% cellpadding ='4' border='1' >
        <tr>
            <th>Select a Category</th>
            <th>Jobs Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>No Students needed</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name = lists >
                    <option name= nothing value= 0 selected >Choose a Category</option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 1>    Advertising     </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 2>    Fiscal          </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 3>    Food            </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 4>    Shopping        </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 5>    Rentals         </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 6>   Setting up       </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 7>    Performances    </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 8>  Registration/Ushering  </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 9>   Master of Ceremonies  </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 10>    Cleaning up   </option>
                    <option name= nothing value= 11>    Others        </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td> <input type=text name=JobName maxlength=50  placeholder='Enter Job Name '></td>
            <td> <input type=text name=Description maxlength=50 placeholder='Enter Description '></td>
            <td> <input type=text name=NoStudent maxlength=50   onkeypress=return isNumber(event) placeholder='ONLY NUMBERS'/></td>
            <td> <input type=text name=dueDate maxlength=50 placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <div align='center'>
        <input type='submit' name='add' value='Add' />
        <input type='reset' value='Clear' />
    </div>
</form>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "must login to see this page..!!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Do let me know if I can clear anything up.